# SSL Certificate on Android not beeing used by Chromium

Tags: android, ssl, chromium, ca, android-8.1-oreo

I am currently trying to reach my own web-service via Chromium on Android 8.1
I have installed the Certificate for the Server, but when I try to reach my service I get a "Your connection is not private" Error.

To install the CA I have downloaded it via Chrome on my desktop and pushed it via USB to my phone.

I then went to Settings -> Security & Location -> Encryption & credentials -> Install from storage and installed it.

The Phone is in the same network as the server is and it knows the FQDN and IP of the server

Edit 1:
To clarify further: it's a self-signed Cert, so the certification-path contains only one certificate, that of the server

Comment: We cannot see the error log or chain of certs. Are you sure you configured the entire chain up to the root on your server? Your Android device won't have any access to intermediate certificates as they cannot yet be cached (as you just installed your trust anchor on which they rely).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Sorry for the lack of clarity. It's a self-signed Cert from the Server, for the Server. So in the trusted-chain is just the Server itself